# How do I use route handler inside a dynamic route in nextjs 13?

Tags: next.js

This is my file structure:

[image]

Say I have it running locally on port 3000, when I hit `localhost:3000/api/create`, the route in `/app/api/create/route.js` handles it and returns the correct response.
but say I have to hit `localhost:3000/dashboard/api/create`, it returns an error since the dynamic route is handling it and the api route isn't being hit. My API is only returning an object `{"hello":"world"}` as response and my home page & dynamic pages are also simple.
All I want is to hit the `/api/create` api route from any dynamic route.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Solutions Tried:
I have tried duplicating the api folder and moving it inside `[...slug]` folder but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting an api route from inside a catch-all dynamic route isn't possible/supported, since catch-all needs gets the complete path of the url.
So I kept my api route outside in my /src folder, and if I have to call it from a page inside my dynamic route using fetch, I call the api route that is specified in my /src folder itself, and I do not need to create an api route inside my dynamic route at all.

Comment: Is there a github issue on this? I would like to read more

Answer (score 0):

For `localhost:3000/dashboard/api/create` to work, you would need a dir structure as follows:

```
app
├─ [slug]
|    ├─ api
|    |   └─ create
|    |        └─ route.js
|    └─ page.js
...
```

`[...slug]` is a catch-all segment. You would need to use either `[slug]` or `[[...slug]]` the optional catch-all segment.

On another note:
From their docs, they don't seem to include the words "create" in the route so sending a POST to `/dashboard/api` implies a create. This would make your dir structure a bit more concise since you can drop the "create" dir:

```
app
├─ [slug]
|    ├─ api
|    |   └─ route.js
|    └─ page.js
...
```

Comment: i can't use an optional catch-all because i'm creating the slug/catch-all folder in the root directory. This is the error message - "`Error: You cannot define a route with the same specificity as a optional catch-all route ("/" and "/[[...slug]]").`"



my requirements are - requests to / would render my root page.js and anything else would render the page.js inside [...slug].
also i agree with dropping the 'create' directory. only reason i made it so that any endpoints hitting `/api/create` would hit the route instead of just `/api`

Comment: This did not work for me with NextJS 13.5,2